# Nested For Loop read Digits

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

Hello I am trying to understand nested for loops a bit better, as they seem pretty useful. Right now I am trying to make a simple program to print out all positive two digit numbers. After it prints out the numbers I want to add the two digits of each number and print out the sum. For example, when it prints out 25, it should print out 2+5=7. The code I have so far is:

```
public class NestedLoops6 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int counter = 10;counter<100;counter++) {

        String fdigit = String.valueOf(counter).substring(0, 1);
        String sdigit = String.valueOf(counter).substring(1,2);
        int suma = Integer.parseInt(fdigit)+Integer.parseInt(sdigit);

        System.out.println(counter +" "+ fdigit+" + "+sdigit+ " = "+suma);

        }
    }
}
```

Now this code runs and satisfies what I intended to do. But, is there a way to get the same result but with for loops instead? I feel like that is something really useful to learn.

Comment: You are already using a `for` loop. What's your question?

Comment: For loop over what? The digits in counter? Or something else?

Comment: Instead of the String.valueof() method, is there a way to use a for loop inside the for loop. I have one for loop to get the numbers from 10 to 99. Is there a way to make a for loop to read/return the indiviual digits from each of those numbers.

Comment: You can use `Scanner` to read the individual digits. `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(counter); int digit = scanner.nextInt(); // counter = 10 and digit = 1` out of the top of my head.

Comment: > I feel like that is something really useful to learn. Isn't it good practice to shy away from "nested" in general? Nested loop are situationally useful but that's about it...

Comment: Yes, you can extract digits from another number by mod and division by 10. Unless you know the number of digits ahead of time you want to keep going until the dividend is zero though, so not normally a 'for'. However this is starting to sound like a homework exercise, so I've changed my mind about writing you an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it might be useful, but I see what you mean, nested loops tend to get a little bit confusing at times.

Comment: Well I am just practicing coding with some exercises online and one was to use a nested loop to solve the problem at hand, and I mean I got the objective done, it's just I wanted to see if I could do it a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1;i<10;i++) {
   for(int j= 0;j<10;j++) {
    String fdigit = String.valueOf(i)
    String sdigit = String.valueOf(j)
    int suma = Integer.parseInt(fdigit)+Integer.parseInt(sdigit);

    System.out.println(fdigit+sdigit+" "+ fdigit+" + "+sdigit+ " = "+suma);

   }
}
```

A nested loop is just another loop in a loop.

Comment: What is the point of `Integer.parseInt(fdigit)` if we know that `fdigit` is result of  `String.valueOf(i)`? This just gives us back `i` which we already have (same for `j`).

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for, I see that even though you use a nested loop you still need to use the Integer.parseInt().  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Upon using this, I see that for loops can be used to read the numbers or at least set the numbers. It is pretty useful if I want to create a 2, 3, 4,. .n. number with varying limits. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Just a fast copy paste without considering the syntax, you are right. @Pshemo